# Inherit parent properties from a Base class with Jpa annotations in Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

All our JPA Entities have an @Id, @UpdateTimestamp, Optimistic Locking etc... My idea is to create some kind of Base class witch contains everything that every JPA Entity needs to have which can be inherited by all of them.

```
open class JpaEntity (

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   var id : Long? = null,

   @UpdateTimestamp
   var lastUpdate : LocalDateTime? = null

   ...
)
```

I trying to find how I can use this class (or any other solutions) so that the devs in our team don't need to redo the same typing over and over.

So far my implementation doesn't have an "Identifier" according to JPA

```
@Entity
class Car (

    @get:NotEmpty
    @Column(unique = true)
    val name : String

) : JpaEntity()
```

Does anyone has an elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create the base class for other entities in the same way as we are doing this in Java (with `@MappedSuperclass` for example):

```kotlin
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class BaseEntity<T>(
        @Id private val id: T
) : Persistable<T> {

    @Version
    private val version: Long? = null

    @field:CreationTimestamp
    val createdAt: Instant? = null

    @field:UpdateTimestamp
    val updatedAt: Instant? = null

    override fun getId(): T {
        return id
    }

    override fun isNew(): Boolean {
        return version == null
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "BaseEntity(id=$id, version=$version, createdAt=$createdAt, updatedAt=$updatedAt, isNew=$isNew)"
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false
        other as BaseEntity<*>
        if (id != other.id) return false
        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return id?.hashCode() ?: 0
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
data class Model(
        val value: String
) : BaseEntity<UUID>(UUID.randomUUID()) { 

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Model(value=$value, ${super.toString()})"
    }
}
```

See my working [example](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-kotlin-batch-insert-demo).

Note for `@field` annotation - without it the `CreationTimestamp`/`UpdateTimestamp` [don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47621831/5380322).

Comment: `data class` on `Model` is not a good approach because underneath Kotlin will override `BaseEntity` `equals` and `hashCode` methods. Instead of `data class Model` you should use only the `class Model`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate `JpaEntity` with either `@Entity @Inheritance(strategy = ...)` or `@MappedSuperclass`. The second seems to be more reasonable for your case, but see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html) (or https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance).

Neither Kotlin (except maybe needing to specify annotation targets like `get:`) nor use of Spring Boot should make any difference here.